# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method loadKoinModules after set minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, koin

My app app has 3 module
`:app`
`:core` (android library)
`:favorite` (dynamic feature, contain an fragment).

I use Koin for dependecy injection. Everything is working fine, but after i set the `minifyEnabled true`, the app crash when i create fragment from `:favorite` on MainActivity.

Here's the log :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxx.moviecatalog, PID: 18272
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method loadKoinModules(Lorg/koin/core/module/Module;)V in class Lorg/koin/core/context/DefaultContextExtKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.koin.core.context.DefaultContextExtKt' appears in /data/app/com.xxx.moviecatalog-ESUZ0KmUkQnb4vTCi7ocOw==/base.apk)
    at com.xxx.favorite.fragments.FavoriteScreenFragment.onViewCreated(FavoriteScreenFragment.kt:35)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1817)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

How i set minifyEnabled in `:app` and `:core`

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Code to create fragment on MainActiviy

```
private val className: String
        get() = "com.xxx.favorite.fragments.FavoriteScreenFragment"

private fun fragmentBuilder(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .commit()
}

private fun instantiateFragment(className: String): Fragment? {
        return try {
            Class.forName(className).newInstance() as Fragment
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Module not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            null
        }
}

private fun moveToFavoriteFragment() {
        val fragment = instantiateFragment(className)
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentBuilder(fragment)
        }
}
```

Proguard rule

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for SQLCipher  ----------
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses interface net.sqlcipher.** { *; }


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson ----------
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Retrofit ----------
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface * extends <1>
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* public *** *(...); }
-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class <3>


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Glide ----------
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule {
    <init>(...);
}
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.load.data.ParcelFileDescriptorRewinder$InternalRewinder {
    *** rewind();
}

-keep public class kotlin.**
```

how i start koin

```
startKoin {
    androidLogger(Level.NONE)
    androidContext(this@MyApplication)
    modules(
        listOf(
            useCaseModule,
            repositoryModule,
            viewModelModule,
            databaseModule,
              )
         )
}
```

I use `loadKoinModules(favoriteMovieModule)` to load the viewmodel module. The app also working fine if i set `minifyEnabled false` in `:app` module, and left `minifyEnabled true` in `:core`

Am i missing something?

thanks :)

Comment: Minifying can change the method name, that's kind of the point